# R: VAR analysis

Tags: r, vector-autoregression

What does "Pr" and "|t|" stand for in the summary?
I'm not good at VAR model analysis.
The codes below is from this web site.(https://qiita.com/saltcooky/items/2d0119ea4a10bab6cff2)

```
> summary(Canada_var)

VAR Estimation Results:
========================= 
Endogenous variables: e, prod, rw, U 
Deterministic variables: const 
Sample size: 81 
Log Likelihood: -150.609 
Roots of the characteristic polynomial:
1.004 0.9283 0.9283 0.7437 0.7437 0.6043 0.6043 0.5355 0.5355 0.2258 0.2258 0.1607
Call:
VAR(y = Canada, p = VARselect(Canada, lag.max = 4)$selection[1])


Estimation results for equation e: 
================================== 
e = e.l1 + prod.l1 + rw.l1 + U.l1 + e.l2 + prod.l2 + rw.l2 + U.l2 + e.l3 + prod.l3 + rw.l3 + U.l3 + const 

          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
e.l1       1.75274    0.15082  11.622  < 2e-16 ***
prod.l1    0.16962    0.06228   2.723 0.008204 ** 
rw.l1     -0.08260    0.05277  -1.565 0.122180    
U.l1       0.09952    0.19747   0.504 0.615915    
e.l2      -1.18385    0.23517  -5.034 3.75e-06 ***
prod.l2   -0.10574    0.09425  -1.122 0.265858    
rw.l2     -0.02439    0.06957  -0.351 0.727032    
U.l2      -0.05077    0.24534  -0.207 0.836667    
e.l3       0.58725    0.16431   3.574 0.000652 ***
prod.l3    0.01054    0.06384   0.165 0.869371    
rw.l3      0.03824    0.05365   0.713 0.478450    
U.l3       0.34139    0.20530   1.663 0.100938    
const   -150.68737   61.00889  -2.470 0.016029 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


Residual standard error: 0.3399 on 68 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-Squared: 0.9988, Adjusted R-squared: 0.9985 
F-statistic:  4554 on 12 and 68 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: Pr = Pearsons coefficient. You use this value to state if a variable is significantly correlated, which depends on the used alpha value (often 0.05). The t value describes how strong the correlation is. The bigger the t value, the more likely to reject the 0 hypothesis. Google on 'p value t value' for a more detailed description.

Comment: @maarvd No. `Pr` stands for probability, not Pearson's correlation coefficient (which is usually denoted by a lower-case `r`). `Pr(>|t|)` gives the two-sided p-value of the `t` statistic. You can calculate the p-values manually to check; for example, `2*(1 - pt(2.723, 68))` gives `0.008204` (for the `prod.l1` term). The factor 2 comes from the fact that we're calculating a p-value for a two-sided test.